# Problem with line breaks in PDF document generated by BIRT

Tags: pdf, birt

I have some cell texts in a BIRT report which do not flow as nicely as I hoped.

For example,

[image]

The text is `Long value resultwithaverylongname whichcannotbreak` and I had hoped that it would be displayed like this:

```
Long value 
resultwithaverylongname 
whichcannotbreak
```

The render options are as follows:

```
renderOptions.setOutputFormat(IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);
renderOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);
renderOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
renderOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_WORDBREAK, true);
```

It seems to me that my desired output is physically possible but I don't know why BIRT does not break on a whitespace and breaks in the middle of the word.

I am using BIRT 4.16 (from Sourceforge). The texts contain normal whitespace (no non-breakable spaces) and are displayed via a `data` object.

3.Sep.21

I now have an example project which I am trying to commit to Github. In the meantime here is a screenshot showing breaks which look good and others which are not...

[image]

The git repo is here: https://github.com/pramsden/test.wordbreak

Answer (score 1):

If the text "resultwithaverylongname" physically fits, then you are right:
BIRT should not break it in the middle of the word.
Your renderOptions seem right (depending of what BIRT version you are using).

At first glance this looks like a bug.

But: In German language, we often have quite long words, and I've created a lot of (complex) PDF reports with BIRT, but I never saw this issue.
So I guess it is a tiny silly detail which causes this.

Just to double-check:

Are the spaces between "Long", "value", "result..." normal spaces (0x20)? or non-breaking spaces?

Which BIRT release are you using?

Are you using a data item or a dynamic text item and if so, is it HTML or plain text?

Can you create a reproducible simple test case and post the rptdesign  file somewhere?

Comment: Thanks. I just added info to the question. I will try to create a simple test case as soon as possible.

Comment: test case is here: https://github.com/pramsden/test.wordbreak

Answer (score -1):

well i don use BIRT , but  try to use (\n),
in my case I use [PDFFlow library](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdf-lib-default) to generate pdf docs, and to make a line-break i just use `\n`

this is a simple example code to create a pdf file and use line break

```
var DocumentBuilder.New()  
  .AddSection()  
    .AddParagraphToSection("Hello world! \n go to the next line")
.ToDocument()  
   .Build("Result.PDF");
```

try it and tell me if it works

Comment: thanks for the repl. I don't know what text will appear so adding `\n` is not an option and not appropriate for this problem